# How can i add this jQuery code to AngularJS 2 application

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to include materialize-css. I have included the jQuery.min.js and the required css and js files to the index.html using script tag. I created a collapsible nav-bar. It requires an initialization script. Where should I put the script in order to initialize the nav-bar. The following is the jQuery code.

```
   $( document ).ready(function(){
       $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
   })
```

My nav.component.html code is

```
 <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i  class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
         <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
         <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
         <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
         <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

app.component.html code is

```
<navbar></navbar>
```

index.html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
      <title>Blood</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
      <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
      <script src="bower_components/materialize/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
      <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
      <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
      </script>
 </head>
 <body>
      <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `$(".button-collapse").sideNav();` to the `ngAfterViewInit` life-cycle hook.

Comment: It worked! Thank you @echonax

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize. It might be easier to work with.

Comment: Hello Erlend, although external resources are very useful, its always good to contextualize its use by providing some examples and tips